# How to put searchbar in the center in Swift

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to create a search bar on the storyboard like the picture below, 
[image]

however, when I run the program, I found the searchbar is not align on the center. 
[image]

I am trying to "Align" and add constraint to the searchbar, but I am not be able to do so
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The searchBar takes the width of the tableView. It seems to me that your tableView has a set width of 600. This is too wide for phones. Try deleting this constraint and setting the right side of the tableView to the trailing space of the container view.

Comment: I didnot manually set the width, how to trailing the the space?

Comment: so in the last picture on the left side you see this hierarchy View > Table View > Search Bar drag this blue line from the tableView to the View. And add select Trailing space to container view or something like that.

Something that should also work is to select something inside the view. Then in the blue bar at the bottom of your screen select the triangle and under all views in view controller press reset to suggested constraints.

Answer (score 2):

@Stefan va der Lee got a good point
In this simple structure, there is a tableview lay inside a view controller. However, the **"Table View"** doesnot align properly. So i just **"Add Missing Constraints"**  to the **"Table View"**

[image]

[image]